# Bringing Nonograms to a New Dimension

Tags: nonogram, four-dimensional

This is a 4D nonogram.

[image]

Rules:

> - Imagine six stacks with six layers of nonograms.
> - Each of the 36 diagrams with numbers aside represents one layer from the top to the bottom of the stack.
> - The numbers within the pale-yellow diagrams belong to the line at the corresponding position from the top to the bottom (or from the left to the right) through all layers of the stack/ hyper-stack.
> - Blank clues meant that the pattern is unknown.
> - All numbers are one-digit numbers. Therefore, 11 means one-one, not eleven!
> - Interpret the final answer with text.

Apologies - Error(s) found

> All errors found have been highlighted and are in red. Please comment if there are any more issues. Thanks!

Comment: Is a blank row meant to indicate that no squares in that row/column are filled in? In the top-left nonogram, 1-2-1 should put a filled square in an unmarked column. Or am I misreading the 4d-nature of the puzzle?

Comment: @Somebody There are rows/columns with "0", so I think the lack of a number means there can be any number of filled cells in that row/column.

Comment: no idea how I missed that but that makes sense. thanks!

Comment: I think there is a mistake, the bottom left is not solvable

Comment: Bottom left looks OK to me (though I could be missing something) but bottom _right_ seems to run into a contradiction very quickly. @OmegaKrypton please check? (And if a correction is needed, please provide an easy way to tell _what's changed_.) Thanks!

Comment: I switch left and right sorry (it's kinda confusing in 4D)

Comment: I also get a contradiction at the small grid completely at the right, second from the top (with 31213 above it) when I combine this grid with the zero clues at its right

Comment: This reminds me of Picross 3D and and Picross 3D Round 2. Of course those puzzles are only in 3D...

Comment: Can I post a partial 'what i have so far' image? I'm still seeing a contradiction (I think the one Reinier pointed out, in that square) and unfortunately I gotta get back to work T_T

Comment: @OmegaKrypton could you maybe also check the fourth row? I have now run into a contradiction twice there

Comment: Like Reinier I get a contradiction in the last grid on the second-from-top row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> Reinier

The solved puzzle is:

> [image]

(I believe that the solution is not completely unique, but at those points I made the choices that seemed most reasonable.)

Now we can read of the following text:

> Answer That I'm Looking For Is Your Username

which explains the given final answer.

Comment: Beat me by a hair! I'm like 5 minutes from finishing mine. Good job!

Comment: sorry for so many errors! please check now ;)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I think the solution should be right now, but there is still an error in the puzzle. Could you maybe also check whether two of the 11 clues above the s and e from "Answer" should actually be 111? (This would make the final text a bit nicer)

Comment: idk why the excel pasting would cut the clues... fix now, thanks

Comment: @OmegaKrypton the solution should now be corrected too

Comment: I think the solution is still not unique, for instance the top-right cell of the 'e' from 'answer' has no clues, so it's impossible to solve completely. Nevertheless, I still enjoyed it, thanks!